# Upload image in Flask and store it in local folder

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to upload an image and pass it to the python code in flask so it can store and call the image locally. From a tutorial I have this code, however there seems to be a problem with the query, the request always ends with 'No file part':

```
if 'file' not in request.files:
    flash('No file part')
    return redirect(request.url)
```

If I check which data is in the request:

```
print(request.data)
print(request.args)
print(request.form)
```

that gives me the following results:

```
b''
ImmutableMultiDict([])
ImmutableMultiDict([('file', '6b6e63084d829d765f318a123f9997d6.jpg')])
```

Here is my python code

```
ALLOWED_IMAGE_TYPES = set(["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"])

def allowed_file(filename):
    print("Check if image types is allowed")
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_IMAGE_TYPES


@app.route("/crop", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def crop():

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No image selected for uploading')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            print("test2")
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            print('upload_image filename: ' + filename)
            flash('Image successfully uploaded and displayed below')
            return render_template('index.html', filename=filename)
        else:
            flash('Allowed image types are - png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
            return redirect(request.url)

    else:
        return render_template("crop.html")

@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_image(filename):
    print('display_image filename: ' + filename)
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename), code=301)
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<p>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</p>
{% if filename %}
    <div>
        <img src="{{ url_for('display_image', filename=filename) }}">
    </div>
{% endif %}
<form method="POST" action="/crop" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file" value="file" id="file" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.files` is a dict object, so checking that the name is in it should work. For some reason it's not, so you could try checking if it's in `keys()` instead, although that should be unnecessary.

```
if 'file' not in request.files.keys():
    flash('No file part')
    return redirect(request.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem in the HTML code, the quotation marks around the curly brackets were wrong.

```
 <img src={{ url_for('display_image', filename=filename) }}>
```